# InApp monthly subscriptions in BB 10

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, subscriptions

I am new to Blackberry 10 cascades. In my current app I need to make InApp subscriptions. I am unaware of how to achive this BB 10.

But I have Integrated the BB 10 Payment Service sample from the link https://developer.blackberry.c... to my current working App. I have also tested the payment in both Testing and Production mode by invoking

PaymentManager::setConnectionMode(PaymentConnectionMode::Test);
PaymentManager::setConnectionMode(PaymentConnectionMode:: Production);

function call from main.cpp.
and It is working fine.
now my question are

1. How to make In app Subscriptions for monthly renewals for BB 10 ? Does the same code work? Do I need to change any thing in my cuurent Integrated code?

Curently I am Invoking from the QML,

```
Button {
text: qsTr("InAPP") + Retranslate.onLanguageChanged 
verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Bottom
horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
onClicked: {
paymentControl.sku = "ABCD XYZ"
paymentControl.getPrice(paymentControl.sku)
paymentControl.purchase(paymentControl.sku)
}
}
```

1. If Subscriptions for monthly renewals are done how the merchant knows about his/her monthly renewals automatically. Is there any Purchase Status API (for Android ) like API for BB 10 also.
2. Does BB 10 app gets a notification /Intimation about renewals from the RIM/ BlackBerry World to BB 10 App?